# C program: error in array push

Tags: c, xml, arrays, char

I just parsed xml and inserted value from it into a char array. But while printing it I got some different output as follows.

```
ȷ
�,
��
```

but actually it should be

```
Alu Tomato
Baigan Bharta
Chicken 65
```

Source code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<libxml/parser.h>
#include<libxml/tree.h>

static void print_element_names(xmlNode * a_node);

char node_name[1024] = "";
char *menu_list[200];
int no_of_item = 0;
char tempstr[1024];
int flag_node = 0;

int main ()
{
    memset (menu_list, -1, sizeof(menu_list));
    parsexml();
    printMenuList();

    return 0;
}


int parsexml() 
{

    xmlDoc         *doc = NULL;
    xmlNode        *root_element = NULL;
    const char     *Filename = "/mnt/jffs2/temp.xml";
    doc = xmlReadFile(Filename, NULL, 0);

    if (doc == NULL)
    {
        printf("error: could not parse file %s\n", Filename);
    }
    else
    {
        root_element = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);
        print_element_names(root_element);
        xmlFreeDoc(doc);
    }
    xmlCleanupParser();

    return 0;
}

static void print_element_names(xmlNode * a_node)
{
    xmlNode *cur_node = NULL;

    for (cur_node = a_node; cur_node; cur_node = cur_node->next) 
    {
        if (cur_node->type == XML_ELEMENT_NODE) 
        {
            sprintf(node_name, "%s", cur_node->name);

            if(strcmp(cur_node->name,"itemName") == 0)
                flag_node = 1;
        }

        if(cur_node->content!=NULL)
        {
            if(flag_node == 1)
            {
                printf("Items\t%s\n", cur_node->content);

                sprintf(menu_list[no_of_item], "%s", cur_node->content);

                //menu_list[no_of_item] = cur_node->content;

                flag_node = 0;

                no_of_item++;
            }
        }
        print_element_names(cur_node->children);
    }
}

int printMenuList()
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<no_of_item; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", menu_list[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <userloginMethodResponse xmlns="http://wsdlclass.wsdlcreat.sims.triesten.com">
      <userloginMethodReturn>
        <itemCode>ALT</itemCode>
        <itemName>Alu Tomato</itemName>
        <itemPrice>0.0</itemPrice>
        <loginStatusId>0</loginStatusId>
        <loginid xsi:nil="true"/>
        <messId>1</messId>
        <password xsi:nil="true"/>
        <schoolId>1</schoolId>
        <userId>60000100</userId>
      </userloginMethodReturn>
      <userloginMethodReturn>
        <itemCode>BAI</itemCode>
        <itemName>Baigan Bharta</itemName>
        <itemPrice>0.0</itemPrice>
        <loginStatusId>0</loginStatusId>
        <loginid xsi:nil="true"/>
        <messId xsi:nil="true"/>
        <password xsi:nil="true"/>
        <schoolId>0</schoolId>
        <userId xsi:nil="true"/>
      </userloginMethodReturn>
      <userloginMethodReturn>
        <itemCode>CHIKK</itemCode>
        <itemName>Chicken 65</itemName>
        <itemPrice>20.0</itemPrice>
        <loginStatusId>0</loginStatusId>
        <loginid xsi:nil="true"/>
        <messId xsi:nil="true"/>
        <password xsi:nil="true"/>
        <schoolId>0</schoolId>
        <userId xsi:nil="true"/>
      </userloginMethodReturn>
    </userloginMethodResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: What happens when you step through the code with your debugger ?

Comment: Am a beginner and i dont have a debugger, Actually its running in device not on my computer.

Comment: `menu_list` is an array of pointers to `char` arrays.  You need to allocate storage for each element before writing to it in `print_element_names`

Comment: This: `printf("%s\n", menu_list[i]);` assumes `menu_list[i]` is a pointer to `char *` that has been initialized to a valid `char *` Where in your code do you do that?

Comment: @simonc really i dont know how to allocate.. can you please help me out.

Comment: @WhozCraig i do not understand your question actually. I have declared menu_list as a char * at line 9. correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @Krish use `malloc` to allocate memory `strlen(cur_node->content)+1` bytes then use `strcpy` to copy into it.

Comment: When you declare a `char *` it only reserves space for a character pointer, or character array pointer, or string (if you want to think of it that way). It doesn't have a valid value in it yet. (Just like if you just say `int x;`, `x` doesn't have a valid value until you assign one.) You need to store pointers in `menu_list` that point to memory space that can hold the menu strings. One way is to loop through `menu_list` and dynamically allocate (with `malloc`) the needed length buffers and store the addresses from `malloc` calls into `menu_list` locations.

Comment: Thanks for all your support guys memory allocation is the problem. I got the solution. And its working now.

Comment: @Krish `menu_list` is a character pointer array. It is not a character pointer (`char *`) as you said in your reply. It is an *array* of two-hundred character pointers `char *`, each of which will be indeterminate and point to nothing valid until you provide valid memory locations for those pointers to hold (such as with dynamic allocation and for that, see simon's comment).

Answer (score 2):

You need to have something like

```
#define MENU_STR_SIZE 64
```

When you declare menu_list:

```
char * menu_list[200] = {NULL};
```

Then, in the loop where you're using sprintf to add strings to menu_list

```
if (menu_list[no_of_item] == NULL){
    if ( (menu_list[no_of_item] = malloc(MENU_STR_SIZE)) == NULL)
        printf("Memory Error!!\n"); /*do some cleanup or quit or whatever you choose*/
}

sprintf(menu_list[no_of_item], "%s", cur_node->content);
```

Then, you need to add a function to free your menu list

```
void menu_list_free(char ** menu_list, int size)
{
    int i;
    for ( i = 0; i < size; i++ ){
        if (menu_list[i])
            free (menu_list[i]);
            menu_list[i] = NULL;
    }
}
```

Note you could also use strcpy rather than sprintf

Edit:

You also need to get rid of your call to memset.  What you're trying to do is like my allocation to NULL above, but -1 isn't a good value for a pointer as it's probably 0xFFFFFFFF or something like that, which might actually be valid memory.

Comment: In his sample `sizeof(menu_list)` *is* the size of the array of pointers, it is not just the size of a singular point, so that statement is wrong.  Agreed, it is inappropriate in the first place (i.e. the OP's code is wrong regardless). If `menu_item` were a dynamically allocated pointer array (not just the array elements, but the array of pointers itself, i.e. `char **menu_item`, then you would be correct.

Answer (score 2):

menu_list is unallocated.

The simplest change to make this program work would be this:

```
< sprintf(menu_list[no_of_item], "%s", cur_node->content);
--
> menu_list[no_of_item] = strdup(cur_node->content);
```

This will accomplish the allocation at the right time.

With this change, I get

```
amrith@amrith-vbox:/tmp$ ./xx
Items   Alu Tomato
Items   Baigan Bharta
Items   Chicken 65
Alu Tomato
Baigan Bharta
Chicken 65
amrith@amrith-vbox:/tmp$
```

I've made no attempt to free the memory and if someone wants to use menu_list again and stick a larger string in it, good luck ;(